# Retrofit Reusable method for all apis

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have following code

```
public void callMatchListApi() {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<NewMatchList> apiList = apiService.getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY);
        apiList.enqueue(new Callback<NewMatchList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewMatchList> call, Response<NewMatchList> response) {
                //NewMatchList  newMatchList=response.body();


                Log.d("ApiCall", String.valueOf(response.body().getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1()));
                //  Log.d("ApiCall_22",newMatchList.getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewMatchList> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ApiCall_Error", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

here `NewMatchList` is pojo modal class.So i need to make this `NewMatchList` to dynamic object so that i can pass it in `callMatchListApi()` to reusable .
I have tried replacing NewMatchList to object reference in parameter and also Class name but it will throw error.Since i am new to android can any one help me to  fix this issue.

Comment: Hi your question is not clear, what does mean callMatchListApi() to reusable?

Comment: @PankajKantPatel. i need to make this method resuable so i can pass modal class to this .right now i have NewMAtchList model instead of that i need to pass pojo class in parameter so i can use same method for all apis

Comment: ok got it, posting solution for that ,please hold on

Comment: @PankajKantPatel.Thanks

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @SAM if i pass Object object in parameter then  in Call<object> it will throw error as unknown class object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use generics if you think `Object` does not help you:

```
public <T> void callApi(T classz) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<T> apiList = apiService.getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY);
    apiList.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            //T  T=response.body();


            Log.d("ApiCall", String.valueOf(response.body().getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1()));
            //  Log.d("ApiCall_22",T.getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            processResponse(response, classz);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ApiCall_Error", t.toString());
        }
    });
}

private <T> void processResponse(Response<T> response, T classz) {
    if (classz instanceof OneModel) {
        processOneModelResponse(response);
    }
    if (classz instanceof AnotherModel) {
        processOAnotherModelResponse(response);
    }
}
```

You see instead of your `NewMatchList` object, we have a generic type `T` and we can pass it as parameter.

And now you can call the method as follows:

`callApi(NewMatchList.class)`

One thing that you might want to refactor a bit is the `apiService.getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY)`.
You might want to extract that method call somewhere outside before calling the method, because I presume that your `apiService` has different methods with different `Call` types.

***Update*:**
You can add a method for processing the business logic for each response that you get. Something like `processResponse` and then you will process each specific type of model (using `instance of`) in its specific method (`processOneModelResponse`, `processAnotherModelResponse`)

Comment: @sfat.thanks your code works fine for me .log returning success.only problem is how i can get response outside.since i cant loop or parse response on onResponse

Answer (score -1):

Hi i suggest to use RxJava with Retrofit service.

app build.gradle

```
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-jackson', version: '2.3.0'
```

ApiHelper class

```
public class ApiHelper {
    public static ApiService getService() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

ApiService class

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("update_token.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Single<ApiRespBean> updateToken(@Field("manufacture") String manufacture, @Field("model") String model, @Field("device_id") String device_id, @Field("fcm_token") String fcm_token);

    @GET("get_all_history.php")
    Single<HistoryRespBean> getAppHistory();

    @POST("update_suggest_name.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Single<ApiRespBean> updateSuggestName(@Field("image_id") int image_id,@Field("suggest_name") String suggest_name);
}
```

ApiRespBean class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "status_code",
        "message",
        "data"
})
public class ApiRespBean {

    @JsonProperty("status_code")
    private Integer statusCode;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Object data;

    @JsonProperty("status_code")
    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status_code")
    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

MainActivity class

```
  ApiHelper.getService().updateToken(Build.MANUFACTURER, Build.MODEL, Build.ID, fcmToken)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(apiRespBean -> {
                                Log.d("TAG","success");
                            },
                            throwable -> {
                                Log.d("TAG","error");
                            });
```

Comment: @Pankaj.Thanks a lot for taking time to help me.Can you able to describe how observable and sbuscribe works since i read before but i didnt get much idea.any way thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi @vision you can read RxJava2 using any book it takes lot to time to read and understand it.you can replace observables to retrofit callable type too.

Comment: @PankajKantPatel how is this answering the question? It seems some random code that you pasted as an answer. Where did you see in OP's question something regarding `get_all_history.php` ?

Comment: @vision will try to post what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

For reusable try this use `Object` generic type in response type and try parse that

```
public void callMatchListApi() {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Object> apiList = apiService.getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY);
    apiList.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
            //NewMatchList  newMatchList=response.body();


            Log.d("ApiCall", String.valueOf(response.body().getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1()));
            //  Log.d("ApiCall_22",newMatchList.getMatchList().get(0).getTeam1());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ApiCall_Error", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @SAM.thanks.i tried this one but getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY) since getNewMatchListCallListCall is  @GET("matches")
    Call<NewMatchList> getNewMatchListCallListCall(@Query("apikey") String apiKey);

Comment: Call<NewMatchList> use Call<Object>